# Image Exif information with php

Tags: php, exif

I have a script that collects image exif information.I am using exif_read_data() function.

But it can't read png or some other format.It works with .jpg and .tif only

How can i get exif information for .png ?

Comment: As the manual states: `EXIF headers tend to be present in JPEG/TIFF images generated by digital cameras` and my bet is that `png` don't have these information in its headers. Have a look at this page: http://dpanswers.com/roztr/content_show.php?id=261

Comment: but in the flciker i upload an image and checked it shows me information named Exif..you can check it..

Comment: Perhaps a png file with a jpg/tiff extension?

Comment: flicker just converts images to .jpg ..thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exchangeable image file format (Exif) is a standard that specifies the
>   formats for images, sound, and ancillary tags used by digital cameras
>   (including smartphones), scanners and other systems handling image and
>   sound files recorded by digital cameras.**It is not supported in JPEG
>   2000, PNG, or GIF.**

Answer (score 1):

[`png` format](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000153.shtml) files may use XMP metadata, not EXIF.